# Wireless adapter on Linux?

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, virtual-machine

I am working on Linux as a virtual (VMware Fusion) and the host is OS X  ,but I faced a problem with network adapter that is :
When I installed the virtual, the internet connection on it shown as Ethernet connection with host,as I knew that because the host used the wireless adapter I can't use it in the virtual at the same time .
My question is : How can I make the virtual use the wireless adapter instead the host, so that the the virtual can get the connection from wireless networks directly not by the host ?

Answer (score 0):

Is the wireless adapter connected via a USB bus (even if internal)?  If so, you should be able to connect the adapter using the instructions at https://pubs.vmware.com/fusion-7/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.vmware.fusion.help.doc%2FGUID-4819DA9E-3575-4C7F-9912-C2FFBA6CEAD6.html&resultof=%22usb%22%20 (doing so will disable the wireless on your host)
If it is connected by a PCI or proprietary Apple bus, then you are out of luck.

Please note that I am not familiar with VMware Fusion as I have a PC that runs Workstation instead, but I do know that both Workstation and Fusion support USB device passthrough.

If your guest system is not OSX, then the built-in wireless might not be compatible with your guest operating system.  In that case, simply purchase a USB wireless adapter that is compatible with your guest operating system (it doesn't have to be Mac compatible because VMware will just forward it to the guest) and set up that adapter within the guest.  After doing so, just make sure to disable the network adapter in the VM so the guest can only use the USB adapter.

Comment: No ,I don't have any USB adapter , I use the internal one, but my question : Is thee a way to use this internal adapter by the virtual OS directly , not by the host ?

Comment: You can only use the adapter directly by the virtual OS if the adapter is connected (even internally) by a USB bus.  Not sure how Mac hardware works, but if the bus isn't based on USB then VMware Fusion cannot forward it to the guest OS.  In this case, the next best thing to do is to set your network adapter to Bridged, so that your virtual OS asks your router directly for its own IP address, separate from the host (it will still think it is connected by Ethernet though).